# Fastest way to store a Large Set of Data (C# ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, caching

A webservice i'm working with sends back a result set that equates to around 66980 lines of XML, .net returns this as a list object.

As the user journey requires that we can reload this set if they step back a page, whats the fastest/best way of storing this result set per-user without slowing everything down.

Ta

--
*many solutions:*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use memcache as a general way of caching queries. Best is that it works across nodes (in case you have more webservers).

Comment: Is there any advantage in using memcache over HttpContext.Current.Cache or say Session

Comment: memcache can be used from multiple nodes (webservers). This way, every webserver is not calculating every (already known) answer again.

Comment: Thanks, we only have 1 server for this project and the resultset is randomised from 13000(ish) records or so and 500 returned so it has to be restricted to cache-per-user.

Answer (score 1):

Save it to HttpContext.Current.Cache, keyed on the user id, possibly something like "MyXml_UserId".

Comment: Is there any advantage in using HttpContext.Current.Cache over memcache or say Session

Comment: Depends on your hosting arcitecture. I'd avoid session as it's confined to the sole page server, (unless you save it back to db). if you only host on one, session would probably be ok. I don't know about memcache.

Comment: Session can be automatically backed by SQL Server, or to a separate state server.

Comment: Yup: "(unless you save it back to db)"

Comment: Both answers are technically correct; it doesn't quite answer which is faster but I think there's very little between the two so I've ticked the one I'm currently using for testing. 
-- 
 Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll just note here that your issue is not unique to web services. You might as easily have retrieved that list from a database, and you'd still want to cache it so you don't have to go to the database again.

Comment: True, I figured I'd be overly verbose.